# Store MySQLi error information in PHP variable

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I'm developing a small enviorment in PHP to capture errors released in MySQL from PHP automatic functions with objects under MySQLi.

Well, my function works if the SQL is correct, due to it return the number of the register.

But if the execution fails, the variable register is empty, it had not store the information of MySQL (for example "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'a, "-"a, "123"a, "-"a, "123"a)' at line 1")

Why it's possible to print with ECHO, but not capable to store?

```
    function execute (sql)
{
[...]
     if ($con->query($sql)) return mysqli_insert_id($con); //Devolvemos el ID
     else echo $mysqli->error($con); //THIS SHOWS THE ERROR
     //else return $mysqli->error($con); //THIS NOT SHOW NEITHER STORE 
}


register = execute(sql);

if (register > 0) echo "The ID register is".$register;
else echo "there was an error: ".$register;
```

Comment: you are doing it wrong. your function should never return an error string instead of insert id

Comment: though such a function should never return insert id either

Comment: @YourCommonSense Well, I know may be it's dirty return a number either a string, its just for simplify. But what is wrong if I want to know which is the ID of the register if the function just add something to one sql table?

Answer (score -1):

Well I saw my error:

Instead of

```
 else echo $mysqli->error($con);
```

is,

```
 else return $con->error;
```

so finally, the code working is:

```
function execute (sql)
 {
 [...]
 if ($con->query($sql)) return mysqli_insert_id($con);
 else return $con->error;
 }

 register = execute(sql);

 if (register > 0) echo "The ID register is".$register;
 else echo "there was an error: ".$register;
```

Comment: @YourCommonSense  mysqli->error($con); to  return $con->error; . I was using a bad syntax